# How to enableBackgroundDelivery for multiple HKQuantityType identifiers?

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

In Below code, I have enabled background delivery for only step count. But I want to enable for multiple identifiers such as burned calories, travelled distance.

Note:
setupBackgroundDelivery function is called from didFinishLaunching.

func setupBackgroundDelivery() {

```
       let stepType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .stepCount)
      
       self.healthStore.enableBackgroundDelivery(for: stepType, frequency: .hourly) { (success, error) in
           if let error = error {
               print("enableBackgroundDelivery error : \(error)")
           }
        
           if success {
               print("background delivery enabled")
           } else {
            print("Error enabling background delivery for type: \(error.debugDescription)")
          }
       }

        let query = HKObserverQuery(sampleType: stepType, predicate: nil) { (query, completionHandler, error) in
             self.fetchAndSaveHealthData() {
                 completionHandler()
             }
         }
         healthStore.execute(query)
}
```

Comment: You will need same thing for other items.

Comment: @ShourobDatta ....we have to add same thing for each identifier in same method or need to create separate method for each identifier.

Comment: In practcile it is convinent seperate methods for each identifire